# ser2net + socat + gammu. socat terminating

Tags: serial-port, socat, sms

I am developing small app that will send SMS using remote device as gateway.

These devices are connected with VPN, but it doesn't matter.

SMS gateway has physically serial port `/dev/AMA0`.
I'm using `ser2net` on SMS Gateway to share serial port over Internet,
and I'm using `socat` to create virtual serial port on VPS and "receive" shared port.

Here are my confings:

SMS Gw:

```
cat /etc/ser2net.conf 
3333:raw:0:/dev/ttyAMA0:9600,8DATABITS,NONE,1STOPBIT
```

VPS:

```
socat pty,link=/dev/tty_remote_serial,waitslave tcp:10.8.0.2:3333
```

I'm using `gammu` to control the SMS device. When I log on VPS and execute this command I see:

```
gammu identify
Device               : /dev/tty_remote_rpi_serial
Manufacturer         : SIMCOM_Ltd
Model                : unknown (SIMCOM_SIM800L)
Firmware             : Revision:1308B08SIM800L16
IMEI                 : 867XXXXXXXXXXX23
SIM IMSI             : XXXXXXXXXX491925
```

And it's perfect. I can use remote serial port and everything works perfect. The problem is when I run `gammu identify` one more time. Device `/dev/tty_remote_rpi_serial` does not exist because `socat` terminated. When I restart `socat` service everything works fine ONCE. I must restart `socat` every closed connection (from mincom) or executed command (`gammu identify`).

Is there a way to prevent `socat` from terminating?

```
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] N read(5, 0x16ea680, 8192): Input/output error (probably PTY closed)
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] N socket 1 (fd 5) is at EOF
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] I shutdown(6, 1)
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D shutdown()  -> 0
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D data loop: sock1->eof=2, sock2->eof=0, closing=1, wasaction=1, total_to={0.000000}
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D select(7, &0x40, &0x0, &0x0, &999.000000)
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D select -> (, 0x40, 0x0, 0x0, &998.974365), 1
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D read(6, 0x16ea680, 8192)
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D read -> 0
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] N socket 1 (fd 5) is at EOF
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] I shutdown(6, 1)
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D shutdown()  -> -1
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] I shutdown(6, 1): Transport endpoint is not connected
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] N socket 2 (fd 6) is at EOF
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] I close(5)
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D close()  -> 0
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D unlink("/dev/tty_remote_rpi_serial")
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D unlink()  -> 0
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] I shutdown(6, 2)
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D shutdown()  -> -1
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] I shutdown(6, 2): Transport endpoint is not connected
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] N exiting with status 0
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D exit(0)
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D starting xioexit()
2016/01/06 04:50:04 socat[4233] D finished xioexit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
while sleep 1; do
    socat pty,link=/dev/tty_remote_serial,waitslave tcp:10.8.0.2:3333;
done
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  We’re looking for substantial answers that provide some explanation and context.  Please don’t post answers that are just code; explain what you are doing.  And do you have a reason for doing `while sleep 1` rather than `while true` or `while :`?